# Switching protection from ‘Full’ to ‘UserInterfaceOnly’

Tags: excel, vba

This is a simple problem, but a bit fiddly to describe…

When my team open a workbook, it is imperative that the sheets are protected – i.e. they cannot change the formulas. So, on the `Workbook_Save` routine, I make all the sheets protected.

So far, so good.

In the `Workbook_Open` routine (and one or two other places), I want to change the protection to `UserInterFaceOnly` so that my code will be able to make changes on the sheets. I use something like:

```
Sheet1.Unprotect Password≔”MyWord”
Sheet1.Protect Password≔”MyWord”, UserInterfaceOnly≔True
```

This all seems to me like it would work, but the trouble is, it doesn’t. After running the lines above, the sheet is still fully protected – i.e. not `UserInterfaceOnly`

I am using 2013, but it needs to work on 2007 & 2010 too.

Any help, tips or pointers will be gratefully received and eagerly applied!
Many thanks

---

Answer to a response...

```
    Sub ReProtTheSheets() 'This one turns full protection on
        shtHidden.Range("iProt") = False
        Call SetProtection
        shtHidden.Range("iProt") = True
        Call FullProtection
    End Sub
    '-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#
    Sub ResetTheSheets() 'This one turns User-Interface protection on
        shtHidden.Range("iProt") = False
        Call SetProtection
        shtHidden.Range("iProt") = True
        Call SetProtection
    End Sub
    '-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#
    Sub SetProtection()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo BackOn

        If shtHidden.[iProt] Then

            For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If IsOriginalSheet(xSheet) Then 'This UDF ensures that sheets added by the user are not affected
                    If xSheet.Name = ExecSumm.Name Then
    '                   Protect ExecSumm differently - Allow Insert/Delete Columns
                        xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                        xSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
                                            AllowDeletingColumns:=True, Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    ElseIf xSheet.Name = Engine.Name Then
                        xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                        xSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    Else
                        xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                        xSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    End If
                End If
            Next xSheet
        Else
            For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If IsOriginalSheet(xSheet) Then 'This UDF ensures that sheets added by the user are not affected
                    xSheet.Unprotect Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                End If
            Next xSheet
        End If
    BackOn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
    '-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#-#~#
    Sub FullProtection()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo BackOn

        If shtHidden.[iProt] Then

            For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If IsOriginalSheet(xSheet) Then 'This UDF ensures that sheets added by the user are not affected
                    If xSheet.Name = ExecSumm.Name Then
    '                   Protect ExecSumm differently - Allow Insert/Delete Columns
                        xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                        xSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
                                            AllowDeletingColumns:=True, Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    ElseIf xSheet.Name = Engine.Name Then
                        xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                        xSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    Else
                        xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                        xSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    End If
                End If
            Next xSheet
        Else
            For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If IsOriginalSheet(xSheet) Then 'This UDF ensures that sheets added by the user are not affected
                    xSheet.Unprotect Password:=shtHidden.[iWord]
                    xSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
                End If
            Next xSheet
        End If
    BackOn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't use curly quotes in the VBE otherwise it wouldn't have compiled. Just in the question I asked. Thanks for your answer though, but on this occasion it isn't that simple...

Answer (score 0):

Your password has curly quotes and VBA doesn't accept them as string delimiters.  You need straight quotes.

```
Sheet1.Unprotect Password≔"MyWord"
Sheet1.Protect Password≔"MyWord", UserInterfaceOnly≔True
```

instead of

```
Sheet1.Unprotect Password≔”MyWord”
Sheet1.Protect Password≔”MyWord”, UserInterfaceOnly≔True
```

This is a danger of copying from Word or similar into the VBA editor.

Comment: I didn't use curly quotes in the VBE otherwise it wouldn't have compiled. Just in the question I asked.

Comment: I just tried using your code in a new workbook and it worked as expected: I was able to edit the sheet through VBA, but not the GUI.  Can you post your code in its entirety?  I'm thinking there's no issue with these two lines, but it may be something else.

Comment: I think it is more arcane than you might think, because it works for me most of the time too, just sometimes is opens unprotected. Here is all the code that is called in the open routine though

Comment: I've added the code at the end of the question - hope that makes sense